# User defined function returns no output?

Tags: function, pycharm, syntax-error, func

As a first timer, I have ran the following code on pycharm:

```
def help_fun(name):
print("Hi"+ name +"!, how may we help you!") 
help_fun("john")
```

the output generated reads:

```
process finished with exit code 0.
```

Nothing more, but as part of the output, is showing again. Please, may I know the reason for such an error?

However, the pycharm works perfectly when somethings as follows is ran:

```
def add_fun(a, b):
sum = a+b

return sum
a=15
b=45

aa=add_fun(a, b)
print(aa)
```

Am I missing some package or something? Thank you.

EDIT: See attached the result even with the proper indentation [image]

Comment: We can't tell exactly what you have written, because all indentation and line breaks have been lost - both are critical parts of Python syntax.  Please put some effort into making your code actually readable - paste it in, select it, and hit the `{}` button on the editor toolbar to format it.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper. I have made the necessary changes. T

Comment: Nope, that code would not do anything but produce a SyntaxError, due to the lack of required indentation.  We can't tell what code is part of the function definition, and what code is after the function definition, without seeing the actual indentation - and I suspect that your problem involves indentation.

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit, with the "proper" indentation and still gives no output but runs successfully. See the picture attached in the questions.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I need double spacing before the output function help_func('John')

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]